# jqGrid hanging with jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.4

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have spent a lot of time trying to get jqGrid working with jquery, with no luck. Eventually, I stripped it down to the barest minimum to isolate the problem:

I have a webpage using  jquery-1.4.2.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.4 (custom, Redmond colours). I create a jqGrid with static content to make it easier. When I refresh the page, the jqGrid loads the content, then the page hangs (i.e. no response to any of the elements in jqGrid, or any other elements on the page). This happens with jqgrid 3.8.4 as well as 4.0.

Any idea what has gone wrong here?

(page below cut down to the barest minimum -- full page vailable if needed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="Generator" content="manual" />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/js/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    init_jqgrid();
});

function init_jqgrid()
{
var mydata = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2010-05-24",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"2111.00"} ,
{id:"2",invdate:"2010-05-25",name:"test2",note:"note2",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
{id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
{id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
...
{id:"29",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"} ];

jQuery("#list47").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: 150,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"}, {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
    {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"}, {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
    {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} ],
   pager: "#plist47",
   viewrecords: true,
   caption: "Manipulating Array Data" });
}); 
});
</script>

...

</head>
<body>
...

<table id="list47""></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea? If I have an incompatible set of components, which is the best upgrade path? jQuery? jQuery UI?

Lars Erlandsen.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-custom ui?

Answer (score 1):

There are just some syntax errors in your JavaScript and HTML code. Look at [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LarsErlandsen0.htm) and [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LarsErlandsen1.htm) small modifications of your code.

I recommend you to verify your HTML code [here](http://validator.w3.org/) and your JavaScript code [here](http://www.jslint.com/).